# Android External Api Coverage is Not coming

Tags: android, ant, build, code-coverage, emma

I have been trying from past 1 month for deducing the Code coverage report of my Android Project which includes External Jars.(I am running on ADT20). Whenever I run

> ant emma debug install test

It Shows 100% coverage for my Android project but the coverage report does not contain the Package and classes of my External Jars. Can any one help me to get the coverage report of Packages and Classes in External Jars either by emma ant build or any Android Code coverage tool, which ever gets my work done.

Thanks

Comment: I was successfull in getting the package of my external jar in my code coverage report, but still the hitting percentage is 0% for my jar packages and classes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest SDK uses emma by putting emma in front of the build:

```
ant emma debug install
ant emma debug install test
```

The first is run from your project director, the second the test directory. Doing so will generate the full coverage report.

for more information see this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

The ADT r20-preview solves this issue by giving access to the full classpath of tested projects and their Library Projects:

http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview

This will give you code coverage reports on your library projects, but you will have to do some modifying of the test target of build.xml to attach the source files too.

See [this Attach Android library](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32421) project source code to Emma report (ant, emma) for more information on how to incorporate emma test coverage for your library projects for the time being.

Example-build.xml:

```
<emma>
                <!-- Grantland: Attach Android library project sources to the emma report -->
                <report sourcepath="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/${source.dir};${tested.android.library.source.dir}"
                                  verbosity="${verbosity}">
                <!-- <report sourcepath="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/${source.dir}"
                                  verbosity="${verbosity}"> -->
                    <!-- TODO: report.dir or something like should be introduced if necessary -->
                    <infileset dir=".">
                        <include name="coverage.ec" />
                        <include name="coverage.em" />
                    </infileset>
                    <!-- TODO: reports in other, indicated by user formats -->
                    <html outfile="coverage.html" />
               </report>
            </emma>
```

ant.properties:

This can be a semicolon delimited list of directories

```
tested.android.library.source.dir=../library/src;etc
```

Comment: I have performed the above steps, but the results are same as earlier. In the Coverage.html report only the packages of my application are included but the package sof external jars in main project are not included in the report. How can I get the coverage report for jars added in my main project.

Comment: I have tried above changes also, but I am not clear about how to exactly add the path to my jars in build.xml and ant.properties file.My jars are present in libs folder of main project.

Comment: Above Changes are to be made in build.xml of main project or build.xml of test project.

Comment: After performing above steps, my coverage report shows the package of external jar, but it is not getting hit. Its coverage percent is 0%. Am I missing something.

Comment: @RohitJindal:remove source.dir from build.properties of test project

Comment: There is no build.properties file in my test project. There is only project.properties , local.properties , ant.properties and build.xml files.

Comment: @RohitJindal:see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223572/emma-reports-0-coverage?rq=1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20601/discussion-between-rohit-jindal-and-ravindra-bagale)

Comment: In recent ADT build.properties file does not exist. Now ant.properties file has replaced build.properties.My ant.properties file only contains tested.project.dir=C:\\Users\\USER\\newsdkworkspace\\stack_and
tested.android.library.source.dir=C:\\Users\\USER\\newsdkworkspace\\stack_and\\libs

Comment: My reports are hitting package of external jar but still there the code coverage of Jar is 0%.